# How to make in auto-generated Excel files so that two rows are not on separate pages

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have auto-generated Excel file from template (which basically duplicates rows and fills in text). After rows with data goes some rows with signatures. Signatures should not be alone on page - at least one data row should be together with signature. All data rows are with automatic height and wrapping text.

Problem is that we do not know how to do this, because we cannot manually assign page breaks and we cannot assign page breaks automatically because we do not know nor height of all cells nor height of page.

Maybe there is some feature for "page non-break"?

Comment: Why is it that you *"cannot manually assign page breaks"*? It seems to me that you can adjust the page breaks in view mode `Page Break Preview`, do you mean you cannot do that for some reason?

Comment: @A.S.H Files are auto-generated and very long. It's inconvenient for users to do that manually.

Comment: I see. In that case I feel that you need some VBA macro, with a predefined pattern that distinguishes signatures rows from data ones.